# How do i display required fields from inner joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

```
 $q= mysql_query("SELECT 
                `products`.product, 
                `products`.price, 
                `cart`.product, 
                `cart`.userid 
                FROM `products` 
                INNER JOIN `cart` ON `cart`.product=`products`.product") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

while($d=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
echo "<td >";echo "<br><b> Product: </b>$d[2]";echo "</td>";
echo "<td >";echo "<b>  Price: </b>$d[1]<br>";echo "</td>";
}
```

This displays inner joined result of tables -products and cart.
product table has product, price and cart table has userid, product.
How do i display the products ordered by $us that is logged in user by listing rows in inner joined table where userid= $us???

Comment: Use `ORDER BY`. And by the way, how was your first question earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Use this mysql query

```
SELECT `products`.product, `products`.price, `cart`.product, `cart`.userid FROM `products` INNER JOIN `cart` ON `cart`.product=`products`.product where cart.userid= $us  order by `products`.product ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql='select 
    p.`product`, p.`price`, c.`product`, c.`userid`
    from `products` p
    left outer join `cart` c on c.`product`=p.`product`
    where c.`userid`="'.$us.'"';

$q=mysql_query( $sql ) or die('error: '.mysql_error() );
```

Assigning an alias to each table makes the final sql shorter and, to my mind, easier to read.

That said, as the `mysql_` suite of functions in PHP are now deprecated and considered insecure perhaps you ought to migrate the code to either `mysqli` or `PDO` to avoid possible sql injection On the same note, by using the `die('error:'.mysql_error())` if there is an error you would reveal to a potential attacker more than you should, not to mention the rest of the page not loading / degrading gracefully.